# Determine what photo thumbnail was clicked and open lightbox with bigger photo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using the [Lightbox_me](http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/) plugin to create a photo gallery from scratch. Right now the way my images are populated on the screen is by using:

```
<?php
require 'DB.php';

    try{      
    $stmt ='SELECT * FROM victoria';
    foreach ($conn->query($stmt) as $row)
        {
        echo ('<div class="photo"> <a href="images/photoGallery/' . $row['name'] .'"> 
               <img src="images/photoGallery/thumbnails/' . $row['name'] . '" /> </div> </a>');

        }
    }  catch (PDOException $e){
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


?>
```

Each photo is stored inside a `div` class named `photo` right now I have 39 photos. Lightbox me works by calling:

```
$('#try-1').click(function(e) {
    $('#sign_up').lightbox_me({
        centered: true, 
        onLoad: function() { 
            $('#sign_up').find('input:first').focus()
            }
        });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If I wanted to invoke Lightbox_me by clicking on a photo thumbnail and opening the larger high resolution inside the lightbox how would I do this?

Comment: What do the #try-1 and #sign_up refer to?

Comment: That is just the example code from Lightbox_me website `#try-1` refers to the div that is clicked and `sign-up` is the Div that is displayed in the lighbox. The `sign-up` div is set to `display: none` on page load when lightbox is invoked it unhides it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have following (not properly nestede)

```
echo ('<div class="photo"> <a href="images/photoGallery/' . $row['name'] .'"> 
           <img src="images/photoGallery/thumbnails/' . $row['name'] . '" /> </div> </a>');
```

First of all, make changes here, make it look like this

```
echo '<div class="photo"><a href="images/photoGallery/' . $row['name'] .'"> 
           <img src="images/photoGallery/thumbnails/' . $row['name'] . '" /></a></div>';
```

Now, register click event on `.photo a`, like

```
$('div.photo a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var img = $('<img/>', {'src':$(this).attr('href')}),
        div = $('<div/>', {'id':'lightBoxWrapper', 'style':'display:none;'});
        $('body div#lightBoxWrapper').remove();
        $('body').append(div.append(img));
        $('#lightBoxWrapper').lightbox_me({centered: true})
});
```